# Using SQL Server as resource locking mechanism

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking, resources

Given a table of logical resource identifiers (one per row), what is the best way for an arbitrary number of database clients to perform the following operations:

- Claim access to a specific resource, if it is not already claimed
- SELECT the next available resource and claim it (similar to above)
- Release a previously-claimed resource

(The table would have a "claimant" column, which would be NULL in unclaimed rows.)

I'm stuck on the atomicity of these operations: would I need a whole-table lock before I SELECT for the requested / next available resource (and afterwards UPDATE, assuming the claim was successful), or is there some more granular way to do this? I don't have a huge volume of data now, but I'd prefer to keep the table as accessible as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically describing a classical queue based workflow, and you should consider using a real [queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190495.aspx).

For the sake of discussion, here is how you achieve what you wish:

- claim specific resource: `SELECT ... FROM resources WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE key = @key`. Will block if resource is already claimed. Use lock timeouts to return exception if resource already claimed. `key` *must* be indexed and unique.
- next available resource: `SELECT ... FROM resources WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST) ORDER BY <accessorder>`. You must define a order by to express the preference of resources (oldest, highest priority etc)
- release a claimed resource: `COMMIT` your transaction.

The gist of the problem is using the right lock hints, and this kind of problem does require explicit lock hints to solve. UPDLOCK will act as a 'claim' lock. ROWLOCK creates the right granularity preventing the server from 'optimizing' to a page lock. READPAST allows you to skip claimed resources. Placing UPDLOCK on the rows will lock the row and allow you to update it later, but will prevent other operations like ordinary read-committed SELECTs that will block on the locked row. The idea is though that your are going to UPDATE the row anyway, which will place an unavoidable X lock. If you want to keep the table more available you can use [app locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) instead, but is significantly harder to pull off correctly. You will need to request an app lock on a string descriptor o the resource, like the key value, or a `CHECKSUM` of the key or it's [`%%LOCKRES%%`](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/29/lockres-collision-probability-magic-marker-16777215/) value. App locks allow you to separate the scope of the 'claim' from a transaction by requesting the app lock at the 'session' scope, but then you have to release the claim manually ('transaction' scoped app locks are released at commit time). Heads up though, there are a thousand ways to shoot yourself in the foot with app locks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A queue is inappropriate because these are essentially permanent resources. Also, I should have clarified that a client would claim the resource for an arbitrary length of time (encompassing multiple SQL sessions); that's where the claimant column comes in. But it sounds like with a transaction + UPDLOCK/ROWLOCK, I can check the claimant column for non-NULL, write to it, and commit.

Comment: The queue does not need to store the resource, but events notifying the workflow of resource availability for processing. Processors pick up the queue message (ie. the 'event') and they go and act on the resource. When done, the place a new event on the queue signaling that the resource is available for the next stage of the workflow. Or they place a timer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) in the queue to resume the workflow on that particular resource after a specific time.

Comment: In my case, the claim lasts the lifetime of the claiming process--I'm using this to split up data hierarchies among multiple servers. But it sounds like I should read up about queues anyway. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has a built in stored procedure called [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx). The documentation describes it as

> Places a lock on an application resource.

Clients can compete for the named lock (you give it the name you want) and once the lock is held, perform the required action. It the client crashes, the lock is automatically released. To programmatically release the lock, you can call [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx)

A posible solution using applocks

- If the claimant is null, try and grab the applock with the same name
- If the applock is obtained, update the row with your claiment id.
- Once the row is claimed, release the applock as no other client will try and claim it now it is already claimed
- When finished, update the claiment to null

Comment: Since these are row-based resources, I can't use this mechanism--but it's good to know.

Comment: Added an example solution to outline how applocks could be used in this scenario